# How I can upload selected file retrofit from onActivityResult?

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipart

I'm trying to upload file to remote server via retrofit. In Postman I did it in such way:

[image]

I did such interface method:

```
@Multipart
@POST("user/upload")
fun uploadFile(@Part("upload_doc") file: RequestBody): Call<EditResponse>
```

and I'm going to send selected file from onActivityResult:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                val file = File(getRealPathFromURI(data.data!!)!!)

                if (file.exists()) {
                    val uploadFile = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload_doc", file.name, file.asRequestBody())

                    val requestBody: RequestBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
                            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                            .addPart(uploadFile)
                            .build()

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is connected with getting file path. As I think you know this is a problem. I tried to use this method:

```
fun getFile(documentUri: Uri): File {
        val inputStream = context?.contentResolver?.openInputStream(documentUri)
        var file: File
        inputStream.use { input ->
            file =
                    File(context?.cacheDir, System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".pdf")
            FileOutputStream(file).use { output ->
                val buffer =
                        ByteArray(4 * 1024) // or other buffer size
                var read: Int = -1
                while (input?.read(buffer).also {
                            if (it != null) {
                                read = it
                            }
                        } != -1) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, read)
                }
                output.flush()
            }
        }
        return file
    }
```

But the server returned me that I had sent wrong file type. So I think that I have two problems:

1. Getting bad file path
2. Sending normal multipart file for all file types not only sending pdf

I think maybe some problems are connected with this file converting line:

```
val uploadFile = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload_doc", file.name, file.asRequestBody())
```

Maybe someone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have a look at RequestBodyInputStream and use an inputstream for the obtained uri.

Comment: @blackapps, maybe you can give some small examples, because after some looking for it I can't figure out the solution?

Comment: I have never used it myself. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as below :

```
fun updateProfile(
        image: File?,
        firstName: String?,
        userName: String)

  {
        
         var picture: MultipartBody.Part? = null
                try {
                    val requestFile: RequestBody? =
                        image!!.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
        
                    picture = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", 
                  image!!.name, requestFile!!)
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                   
                }
    
    
     val userName: RequestBody = userName
                .toRequestBody(MultipartBody.FORM)
    
      val name: RequestBody = firstName!!
                .toRequestBody(MultipartBody.FORM)


    File file = new File(mediaPath);  
    File file1 = new File(mediaPath1);  
    // Parsing any Media type file  
    RequestBody requestBody1 = 
         RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"),file);  

    RequestBody requestBody2 = 
         RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"),file1);  

    MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload1 = 
        MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file1", file.getName(), 
           requestBody1);  

    MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload2 = 
      MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file2", file1.getName(), 
       requestBody2);  

      postProfile(image,name,username,fileToUpload1 ,fileToUpload2)
    
         
    }
```

and change your retrofit Call to this :

```
 @Headers("Accept: application/json")
 @Multipart
 @POST(yourEndPoint)
 fun postProfile(
     @Part picture: MultipartBody.Part?,
     @Part("name") name: RequestBody?,
     @Part("user_name") user_name: RequestBody,
     @Part filea: MultipartBody.Part?,
     @Part fileb: MultipartBody.Part?
   
 ): Deferred<Response<yourClass>>
```

Comment: but here I can attach only images, maybe you can suggest smth more flexible for all file types? anyway thank you for your response )

Comment: @Andrew I've updated my answer. Hope this help